# How do I set all the new frames open inside the same window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am doing a project in Java using NetBeans. My Login form will open the main menu form. It will contain many options and each option will open a separate `JFrame`. I want all the frames to be opened inside the main window. Not in a separate window.

Comment: Okay, to start with, no, you can't embed an existing `JFrame` inside another `JFrame`.  You should, instead, consider using a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or [`JDesktopPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) instead. As general piece of advise, you should avoid extending directly from `JFrame` as your primary container(s) as it leads to these problems - you're going to have to do a lot of rework to make it work the way you want

Comment: @MadProgrammer How about I use J internal frame inside a j frame??

Comment: A `JDesktopPane` is a required container for `JInternalFrame` - just note that the MDI paradigm has been deprecated since before Windows 95

Comment: @MadProgrammer So I have to place a `JDesktopPane` inside a `JFrame` and 'JInternalFrame' inside the `JDesktopPane`??

Comment: More or less....

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much

Comment: @MadProgrammer Given the OP is talking about one of the 'frames' being a log-in, I'd think a dialog would be the best option here. Failing that, a `CardLayout`. But card layout seems a bit quirky here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I’ve used CardLayout for login before, but it comes down to needs